# Expected value and linear transformations

Tags: probability

I just came across a proposition in a book about expected utility and I am not sure if it is true or how to prove it.

The statement is that for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and a utility function $u$ (I think it is non-decreasing, but I do not know if this makes a difference) if the expected value of $u(X)$ is bigger than or equal to the expected value of $u(Y)$,
the same applies to the random variables $aX+b$ and $aY+b$ with $a>0$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you maybe give the definition of a utility function?